# Raising a subspace to the zeroth power?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was looking over some linear algebra problems, and I encountered the following:

For $T:V\rightarrow W$, $V,\,W$ are finite-dimensional.  Prove that
\begin{align*}
N(T^t)=(R(T))^0
\end{align*}

I think this book uses syntax different from the one from which I learned linear algebra.  But I'm not sure what $T^t$ and $(R(T))^0$ are even taken to mean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is some very weird notation, but it probably means that the nullspace of $T$-transpose is equal to the orthogonal complement of the column space of $T$.

Comment: @EricStucky Ahh... Nicely done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that this gets out of the unanswered queue:

This is some very weird notation, but it probably means that the nullspace of $T$-transpose is equal to the orthogonal complement of the column space of $T$.

As Bye_World mentions in the comments, this can be done without an inner product: the kernel of the adjoint of $T$ is equal to the annihilator of the image of $T$.

Comment: It's a fairly common notation for the annihilator (see it used for instance in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Quotient_spaces_and_annihilators)), which is the generalization of the orthogonal complement.

Comment: I didn't know that, but it's nice since it removes the requirement of an inner product.